# CSS HTML Как разместить текст так, чтобы он не высосысался за кнопку

Tags: html, css

Есть кнопка, внутри нее текст. Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы длинный текст разместился так, чтобы не высовывался с правой стороны. Чтобы его обрезало на ширину кнопки.

```
     <button type="button" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; 
      float: left;  box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 10px;   
      font-size: 30px; white-space: nowrap;"
      data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Tevhjjvjjvjvvjvjvjvvjyyvjvyjvyjvyjvyjvjvkkhkukuknknkubkuukkubkbbbkbukbkbkkuukbkuukukbkkbkukukukubkubxt
                    </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы обрезало, добавляем `overflow: hidden;`

```html
     <button type="button" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; 
      float: left;  box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 10px;   
      font-size: 30px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;"
      data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Tevhjjvjjvjvvjvjvjvvjyyvjvyjvyjvyjvyjvjvkkhkukuknknkubkuukkubkbbbkbukbkbkkuukbkuukukbkkbkukukukubkubxt
                    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё способ "красивой" обрезки текста, при помощи свойства [`text-overflow: ellipsis;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) которая добавит в конце `...`(троеточие).
Так же, некоторые браузеры поддерживают кастомные символы у `text-overflow` (пример у кнопки ниже, обрежется с `.. :3` в конце)

```css
button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

button.custom {
  text-overflow: '.. :3';
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Tevhjjvjjvjvvjvjvjvvjyyvjvyjvyjvyjvyjvjvkkhkukuknknkubkuukkubkbbbkbukbkbkkuukbkuukukbkkbkukukukubkubxt</button>

<button type="button" class="custom" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Tevhjjvjjvjvvjvjvjvvjyyvjvyjvyjvyjvyjvjvkkhkukuknknkubkuukkubkbbbkbukbkbkkuukbkuukukbkkbkukukukubkubxt</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, красивый способ, а можно ли вместо троеточия вставлять box-shadow?

Comment: @ИльяКузьмич, увы, тут уже при помощи скрипта